# How can i get a box with text to size down with the image?

Tags: html, css

i have two boxes with text, and two images next to the text. the first box with the images is shrinking fine, but the second box with the exact same code is shrinking different. so its becoming smaller and the text is moving down in the box. i just want both boxes to scale the same.
or is there a better way to align these two divs next to each other to get the same effect?

i want the box div and image div to be side by side (its a long image)and when i resize the screen i would like the images to be below the box div.

```css
.section2 {
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 55px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 0.90);
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.section3 {
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 0.90);
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.archimg,
.galleryimg {
  width: 93%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 8px solid white;
  height: 94%;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.archboxed,
.galleryboxed {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1.00);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: didot italic, didot, arial italic, arial, times new roman;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 176px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="section2">
  <div class="archboxed">
    <h3 id="h3arch">TITLE</h3>
    <p>Paragrapgh text</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img class="archimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="architectrender">
  </div>
</div>

<!--this is the second box that won’t respond-->
<div class="section3">
  <div class="galleryboxed">
    <h3 id="h3gallery">TITLE</h3>
    <p>Paragraph text </p>
  </div>

  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="galleryimg" alt="galleryimage"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So something like this

```css
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Say you have a container or something similar (just an example)

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <img src="https://..." />
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
```

And for extra small screens you could do something like this in your CSS file:

```css
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
.section2 {
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 55px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 0.90);
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.section3 {
  height: max-content;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(47, 46, 46, 0.90);
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.archimg,
.galleryimg {
  width: 93%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 8px solid white;
  height: 94%;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.archboxed,
.galleryboxed {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1.00);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: didot italic, didot, arial italic, arial, times new roman;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 176px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}


/* ANSWER --- */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .section2 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="section2">
    <div class="archboxed">
      <h3 id="h3arch">TITLE</h3>
      <p>Paragrapgh text</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img class="archimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="200" height="200" alt="architectrender">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--this is the second box that won’t respond-->
  <div class="section3">
    <div class="galleryboxed">
      <h3 id="h3gallery">TITLE</h3>
      <p>Paragraph text </p>
    </div>

    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="200" height="200" class="galleryimg" alt="galleryimage"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but this didnt fix the box. when i size down the page the second box is still not responding correctly.

Comment: Can you explain how it's not responding? If you look at the Code Snippet you can see that the image moves under the text. I know it resizes but this can be fixed by just restricting it's height and width with CSS.